# How to get each value in <li> and <span> tag using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap some data from a site https://www.cellartracker.com/m/wines/12344. I am not able to understand that how to get each value which doesn't belong to any class in  tag. Following is the site's code that I am looking to:

```
<ul class="twin-set-list">
        <li><span>Vintage</span> 2000</li>
        <li><span>Type</span> Red</li>
        <li><span>Producer</span> Balnaves of Coonawarra</li>
        <li><span>Varietal</span> Cabernet Sauvignon</li>
        <li><span>Designation</span> The Tally Reserve</li>
        <li><span>Vineyard</span> n/a</li>
        <li><span>Country</span> Australia</li>
        <li><span>Region</span> South Australia</li>
        <li><span>SubRegion</span> Limestone Coast</li>
        <li><span>Appellation</span> Coonawarra</li>
    </ul>
```

Value like 2000, Red etc don't have any class so what is the way that I can use to get the data. I have tried the following code (only html part is given below) in python:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<ul class="twin-set-list">
            <li><span>Vintage</span> 2000</li>
            <li><span>Type</span> Red</li>
            <li><span>Producer</span> Balnaves of Coonawarra</li>
            <li><span>Varietal</span> Cabernet Sauvignon</li>
            <li><span>Designation</span> The Tally Reserve</li>
            <li><span>Vineyard</span> n/a</li>
            <li><span>Country</span> Australia</li>
            <li><span>Region</span> South Australia</li>
            <li><span>SubRegion</span> Limestone Coast</li>
            <li><span>Appellation</span> Coonawarra</li>
        </ul>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

need = {}

for li_tag in soup.find_all('ul', {'class':'twin-set-list'}):
    for span_tag in li_tag.find_all('li'):
        field = span_tag.find('span').text
        value = span_tag.find('span').text
        need[field] = value

print(need)
```

Can anyone advice me that how I can extract that data?

Comment: When you loop over the result of `find_all('ul')`, you're looping over all the matching `<ul>` elements (and there's only one here). You want to loop over the `<li>`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `contents` attribute of a `bs4` object:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = [[getattr(c, 'text', c).strip() for c in i] for i in soup(html, 'html.parser').find_all('li')]
```

Output:

```
[['Vintage', '2000'], ['Type', 'Red'], ['Producer', 'Balnaves of Coonawarra'], ['Varietal', 'Cabernet Sauvignon'], ['Designation', 'The Tally Reserve'], ['Vineyard', 'n/a'], ['Country', 'Australia'], ['Region', 'South Australia'], ['SubRegion', 'Limestone Coast'], ['Appellation', 'Coonawarra']]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sir.... I am going through it. but where should i pass the url of the site for your code?

Comment: @sonu You will have to use the `requests` or `urllib` module to retrieve the site source, which you can then assign to the `html` variable.

Comment: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: @sonu This works when I run it on Python3.7. Are you still using the original HTML snippet from your question, or are you using the full HTML page?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your code by :

```
field = span_tag.find('span').text 
value = span_tag.text.replace(field,'')
```

It's not very clean but it works with your code.

Comment: It's does the job ...Great

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
for li_tag in soup.find_all('ul', {'class':'twin-set-list'}):
for span_tag in li_tag.find_all('li'):
    field = span_tag.find('span').text
    value = span_tag.text
    value = value[len(field)+1:]
    need[field] = value
```

Just in case, if you have same field in "value", don't replace it but using subtring instead.